# not found. You need to call "Get.put(FoodController())" or "Get.lazyPut(()=>FoodController())"

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I'm creating routes with bindings inside my application , but whenever i navigate from main screen to the home scree, it throws an exception that i need to initialize the controller which what i already did in the homebinding class , i need some help thank you .

- This is the error throwin

```
 The following message was thrown building HomeScreen(dirty):
"FoodController" not found. You need to call "Get.put(FoodController())" or "Get.lazyPut(()=>FoodController())"
```

- This is my main screen

```
void main() {
  runApp(GetMaterialApp(
    home: const MyApp(),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    initialBinding: HomeBinding(),
    getPages: [
      // using HomeBinding() class for home and details screen since i'm going to use the same controller for both
      GetPage(name: '/', page: () => const MyApp()),
      GetPage(name: '/home', page:  () => const HomeScreen(),binding: HomeBinding()),
      GetPage(name: '/details', page: () => const DetailsScreen(), binding: HomeBinding())
    ],
  ));
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  const HomeScreen();
  }
}
```

- This is my home binding class

```
 class HomeBinding extends Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
     Get.lazyPut(() => () => FoodController());
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
Get.lazyPut(() => () => FoodController());
```

by

```
Get.lazyPut(() => FoodController())
```

---

You can also specify the Type with

```dart
Get.lazyPut<FoodController>(() => FoodController())
```